# Return object only if object could be properly created

Tags: c#, .net, object

I'm very new to C# programming and I'm struggling a bit with OOP.

I have created a class with a method that analyzes a text file and creates an object based on its content. I want this function to return an object that contains some of the information in the text file only if the text file is in the correct format.

I call the function to analyze the text file like this:

```
        pokerHand newHand;
        newHand = new pokerHand();

        AnalyzePokerHand.importHand("c:\\text.txt");  

        newHand = AnalyzePokerHand.getAnalyzedHand;
```

If text.txt isn't a poker hand history file, or is in the wrong format etc., I don't want `newHand` to be filled with garbage information about the hand.

What is the correct approach if I would like to pass a path to a text file in and return an object with information about the hand only when the function was successful?

Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning null is the best way if you want to indicate that no data is available. 
The other advantage of this approach is it will  throw null pointer exception if you try to access the member variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options:
I assume you have a `pokerHand Parse(string path)` method, where `path` is the location of the text file.
You could either return null, like this:

```
if(!filePresent || incorrectFormat)
     return null;
```

Or, you could use a `TryParse` approach instead. Change the signiture of the method to this: `bool TryParse(string path, pokerHand result)`.
If the file is valid, you set `result` as the output, and return true. If not, you return false. You call it this way:

```
pokerHand p;
if(!TryParse(@"C:\t.txt", p))
    //parse failed
else
    //parse was successful, p is the result
```

P.S - In C#, we usually use `CamelCase` for class names - so, by convention, your class should actually be called `PokerHand`.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two options in this case: return `null` in the event of failure, or use a `TryParse` style method with an out param (as an example look at [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)):

```
public static bool TryLoad(string filePath, out PokerHand pokerHand)
{
  pokerHand = null;
  ...
  if (fileNotLoadable) return false;
  ...
  pokerHand = loadedPokerHand;
  return true;
}
```

Useable like so:

```
PokerHand pokerHand;
if (AnalyzePokerHand.TryLoad("c:\\text.txt", out pokerHand))
{
  // Use pokerHand here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A logic such as this should be sufficient

```
newHand = AnalyzePokerHand.importHand("c:\\text.txt");
if(newHand == null)
{
     // Message to your user about invalid file....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If garbage data is likely to be an exceptional circumstance, then you could [throw an Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to indicate an error. This causes the program to jump to some error handling code that you defined, so you can alert the user or gracefully deal with the error.

E.g.:

```
try {
    newHand = AnalyzePokerHand.importHand("c:\\text.txt");
} catch(HandException he) {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid hand!");
}
```